# Instantiate clone not being destroyed on Collision enter

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Trying to destroy player when hit the backWall. It works good with the player being in scene from beginning "ball"

but it doesn't destroy the clone of a ball, Debug.Log is still running like for the firs time and every time it hit the wall so it is called, but why it doesn't destroy the object?
ballClone its a prefab.

any advice ?

```
public class BackWall : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject ball;



public static bool playerDestroyed = false;



public GameObject ballClone;



public void Spawn()
{
  GameObject playerclone = Instantiate(ballClone, new Vector3(-1.5f, 1.1f, -8f), 
Quaternion.identity);
    playerDestroyed = false;

    Destroy(ballClone, 10);


    StartCoroutine(waittoDestroy(7));
}

IEnumerator waittoDestroy(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    playerDestroyed = true;
}


public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other)
{
    

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {

        Destroy(ball);
        Destroy(ballClone);

        
        
        playerDestroyed = true;

        Debug.Log("Ball should be destroyed");
    }

    
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you describe it it sounds like you are trying to destroy the **Prefab Asset** `ballClone`!

What you rather want to destroy is the created **Instance** of this prefab: `playerclone`.

You should probably store this instance reference and use e.g.

```
GameObject playerclone;

public void Spawn()
{
    playerclone = Instantiate(ballClone, new Vector3(-1.5f, 1.1f, -8f), Quaternion.identity);
    playerDestroyed = false;

    Destroy(playerclone, 10);  

    StartCoroutine(waittoDestroy(7));
}

IEnumerator waittoDestroy(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    playerDestroyed = true;
}  

public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other)
{
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player")) return;
    
    Destroy(ball);
    Destroy(playerclone);       
        
    playerDestroyed = true;

    Debug.Log("Ball should be destroyed");
}
```